# Declare a bean using annotations and parent abstract bean (which is declared in XML file)

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired, spring-bean

I have a Spring project which uses XML and annotations for declaring beans. I`m trying to declare new beans using annotations. There are abstract beans without implementation:

```
<bean id="parentBean1" parent="parentBean2" abstract="true">
    <property name="service1" ref="service1" />
    <property name="service2" ref="service2" />
    <property name="service3" ref="service3" />
    <property name="value1" value="123456" />
</bean>

<bean id="parentBean2" abstract="true">
    <property name="newservice1" ref="newservice1" />
    <property name="newservice2" ref="newservice2" />
    ...
    <property name="newservice10" ref="newservice10" />
</bean>
```

Those beans are used to declare other beans using XML:

```
<bean id="bean1" parent="parentBean1" class="MyClass">
    <property name="target" ref="bean2" />
</bean>
```

Is it possible to declare bean with id bean1 using annotations? I know that it could be done like in example:

```
@Configration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Autowired private Service1 service1;
    @Autowired private Service2 service2;
    ....

    @Bean
    public MyClass myClassBean() {
        MyClass myClassObj = new MyClass();
        myClassObj.setService1(service1);
        myClassObj.setService2(service2);
        ...
    }
}
```

Using annotations I would have to autowire about 35 services. Is there any simple way to do this using annotations? Is it possible to set parent bean which have no class? Or maybe the only way is to use XML?

Thanks for an explanation.